# How to add ModelStateDictionary in Code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I am developing the MVC app.

I am trying to validate control but cant see `ModelState.AddRuleViolations` property how to add ref ?

I have already added `System.Web.Mvc` library in class.

but cant see the `ModelStateDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're doing your validation inside of `Controller`, you should see `ModelState` property on it.